# Related rates question Particle moving along a curve

Tags: calculus

A particle P is moving along the curve $y=2/x $ so that the xx coordinate is increasing at a rate of $2 m/s$. The line Segment between Origin and P forms an angle θθ between the line segment and the positive xx-axis Compute the rate of change of θθ with respect to time when the particle passes through x=2x=2.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes i have no idea how to solve it can you please help me

Comment: What does $x=2x=2$ mean?